# Spring XML inner bean question

Tags: spring

I have created a spring bean that contains a list of other beans, like so:

```
<bean name="InventoryManager" class="InvManager">
  <property name="slots">
    <bean class="HeadSlot" />
    <bean class="ShoulderSlot" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </property>
</bean>
```

The problem, though, is that elsewhere I have used an `@Autowired` annotation in another class to grab a list of all beans implementing a certain interface that some of these inner beans implement, like so:

```
@Autowired
public void registerInventoryHandlers( List<InvSlot> slots ) {
    //... do some setup stuff with beans that implement the InvSlot interface.
}
```

The problem here is that apparently the "inner beans" defined in XML are not part of the `@Autowired` list.  However, giving all of these slot beans names and then referencing them from the XML seems unnecessary and ugly.

Is there a way to define a bean inside another bean, but not be an "inner" bean?  Or is there a better way to handle this design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beans defined inside other beans are, by definition, "inner" beans. The docs say:

> Inner beans are always anonymous and
>   they are always scoped as prototypes.
>   Please also note that it is not
>   possible to inject inner beans into
>   collaborating beans other than the
>   enclosing bean.

**edited to remove stuff that was poorly thought out, irrelevent or just plain wrong**

I suggest that rather than autowiring the list of `InvSlot` beans, you autowire yourself with the `InvManager` bean instead. You can then ask the `InvManager` for the list of `InvSlot` beans, while keeping your list of inner bean definitions inside the `InvManager` definition.

Comment: Ah, to the contrary!  @Autowired has some surprising, lesser-known uses.  To quote Spring's documentation: "It is also possible to provide all beans of a particular type from the ApplicationContext by adding the annotation to a field or method that expects an array of that type"

Comment: Bloody hell, so it does. I thank you sir, you've taught me a new thing :)

Comment: I tried to use it to power a sort of "don't need to register yourself" event queue and thought myself bloody clever.  But then I ran into this particular can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using @Component works very nicely.

```
@Component class InvManager {
    ...
    @Autowired
    public void registerInventoryHandlers( List<InvSlot> slots ) { ... }
}
```

and

```
@Component class HeadSlot implements InvSlot { ... }
```

and

```
@Component class ShoulderSlot implements InvSlot { ... }
```

Your configuration becomes

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar"/>
```